# Jekyll as a Frontend Framework - Workflow Solution needed

Tags: frameworks, jekyll, frontend, liquid

This is a copy from my thread in the [Jekyll-Forums](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/jekyll-as-a-frontend-framework-workflow-solution-needed/1182/1)

### Situation

At our company we go through the same phases for every project:

1. Design
2. Presentation
3. Development

Unfortunately we are so tightly bound by the sheer number of projects, that we haven't updated our frontend-workflow for years. We are still wandering the old road:

1. Design (Photoshop)
2. Presentation (convert psd to jpg Screenshots & Mockups)
3. Development (convert psd to html)

I always hate to see how much time and money we're leaving on the table by trodding along this path. Each step is completely seperated from the others. And... ah well, I guess I dont have to list all the disadvantages this approach comes with.

I'd like to change that and create a sophisticated & flexible frontend framework for us.

### Goal

For this Jekyll seems just right, since its fast and there are some nice automated styleguide-solutions out there. (eg [this one](https://github.com/jeromecoupe/jekyllstyleguide))

Overall this is the plan:

[image]

**In this workflow I see the following advantages:**

1. Very fast & flexible (almost no extra work)
2. Much better Output (live-prototype instead of screenshots)
3. Happy Developers (styleguide instead of huge psd file)
4. Better connection between Design, Presentation & Development

### Problem

I can see everything coming together nicely, but I'm wondering how one would do this part:

[image]

1. You have a Master-Version of the Framework with every possible component in it.
2. To start working on a new project you create a fresh instance of it that only includes the components you need. Only those components will be part of the automated styleguide.

Of course I could just keep the Master-Framework somewhere, copy-paste it for each new project and delete the uneccessary componenty by hand. But I guess this is just asking for trouble.

Does anyone know a better solution for this?
Some kind of generator, that could do this?

Thanks for any kind of advice. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question.

What you're trying to do is called [atomic design](http://patternlab.io/), and this can be done with Jekyll.

By using [includes](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes), you can build a powerful set of components like :

```
{% include fish.html param1="truite" param2=page.variable %}
```

And you can then get datas inside included files with :

```
{{ include.param1 }}
```

or

```
{% if include.param2 %}
  ...
```

So, yes !, you can get out of this old fashioned design workflow with Jekyll.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a closer look at includes and collections.